# How does the flux density act on the conductor in the slot of a rotor?

Tags: dc-motor, basic

Following picture shows north pole, airgap, rotor.
The conductors are placed in the slots.
It seems ***almost all the flux density is passing through the low reluctance rotor metal part***.
Not much flux is cutting the conductors in the slots.
With no flux, how can there be any torque on the conductor?

[image]

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don't think you would normally wind a motor like that if adjacent wires are meant to be part of the same coil. That would be equivalent to very small coils relative to the pole face. You get entire coils underneath the pole face for extended periods of time in that case. I think you normally overlap the coils so the wires in your photo alternate in phases so the wire of one phase leaves the pole face while the wire of another phase enters the pole face. So coil area and pole area are similar so that the entire area of a coil is under the pole face only for an instant.

Answer (score 2):

> *With no flux, how can there be any torque on the conductor?*

The flux doesn't have to "cut through a conductor" to either induce voltage or produce torque or movement; it's quite sufficient (and sometimes preferable for other reasons) to have the flux totally surround the conductors and not come into contact at all.

Comparison: An ideal transformer with a very high permeability core - hardly any flux leaks from the core at all (due to its very low reluctance) yet, it still produces the same output voltage on the secondary and can still deliver the same sorts of load currents when compared to a much higher reluctance (and leaky) core.

Comment: oh like if it were a generator, emf induced in a loop would be \$E = -\frac{d\phi}{dt}\$, where \$\phi\$ is flux through some surface enclosing the loop. The flux doesn't need to touch the loop.  I think I get it. It just seems weird in a motor haha Happy New Year!

Comment: How do you reconcile that with the simple scenario set up by the Lorentz force equation of a straight wire moving through a magnetic field?

Comment: @DKNguyen Pretty sure you mean a "***current carrying wire*** moving through magnetic field" I have the same thought and got stuck now. (My textbook has a similar linear motor example. There the straight wire continues to accelerate until the backemf equals the supply voltage, then it moves at *constant speed*;  because the current becomes *0* when the backemf equals supply voltage..)

Comment: @across Well, not necessarily current carrying (after all it doesn't have to be a loop, especially if it's an infinite wire). The voltage is induced which I guess is a result of some charge movement if you want to call that current even if it's not continuous. If it's closed to be a loop then continuous current results from the voltage. I mentioned straight to remove overlap with loop area. so either an infinite straight wire or a loop much larger than the area of magnetic flux such that only one and only one side of the loop crosses the flux.

Comment: @DKNguyen  I see your point now. Lorentz force \$q v \times B\$ can push electrons to one end and can create potential difference(Hall effect?). And \$\frac{d\phi}{dt}\$ can also do the same when we consider a loop. But lorentz force doesn't need a loop. Very interesting... Thank you for pointing it out. I'll need to think...

Comment: @Andy aka How can a lorentz force be generated on the current carrying conductors if there is no magnetic flux penetrating them? \$F\propto I\cdot B\$ but if there is no flux through the current carrying conductors then B must be zero through them and hence surely force is zero as well?